# Writing AVRO fixed type from JSON in NIFI

Tags: json, apache-nifi, avro

I'm trying to convert a NiFi flow file containing JSON to an AVRO record.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to deal with a fixed type in AVRO, i.e. how to specifiy the proper JSON for converting to fixed?

Currently I'm using the ConvertJsonToAvro-processor.
The AVRO output schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Message",
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "MAC",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "fixed",
      "name" : "MY_FIXED_TYPE",
      "size" : 6
    }
  }]
}
```

The input JSON-forms I tried are

```
{ "MAC": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }

{ "MAC": "012345" }

{"MAC":"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005"}

{"MAC":{"MY_FIXED_TYPE": "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005"}}
```

Unfortunately none of them worked for me.
I also tried the ConvertRecord-processor instead of the ConvertJsonToAvro-processor. Also without any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation, it looks like the ConvertJsonToAvro processor ***can't*** be used to generate Avro `FIXED` or `BYTES` datum.  This is likely a bug with NiFi and how the processor uses Avro.

If I'm not mistaken:

1. The NiFi ConvertJsonToAvro uses the KiteSDK to interpret JSON into Avro data.  This JSON-to-Avro conversion is *not* the same as Avro JSON encoding from the specification.
2. This processor reads the incoming string into a [jackson JsonNode](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/blob/cdd699a1818c8d6c573b2789ef2edf9d340c0827/kite-data/kite-data-core/src/main/java/org/kitesdk/data/spi/JsonUtil.java#L65).
3. `FIXED` and `BYTES` types need to correspond to a JsonNode where [`isBinary()` is true](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/blob/cdd699a1818c8d6c573b2789ef2edf9d340c0827/kite-data/kite-data-core/src/main/java/org/kitesdk/data/spi/JsonUtil.java#L324).
4. As far as I can tell, parsing a JSON string with Jackson *never* generates such a JSON node.

I would raise a [NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) about this, or an issue on the KiteSDK.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this answer does not apply to NiFi JSON to Avro conversion.  My apologies for the mistaken assumption!**  I'm unsure of the best practice for an answer known to be wrong.

An example of a "correct" Avro JSON encoding for the bytes type is given [in the spec](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.1/spec.html#schema_record).  I think you're looking for:

```
{"MAC":"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005"}
```

Or alternatively (for a fixed schema in a union):

```
{"MAC":{"MY_FIXED_TYPE": "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005"}}
```

You can correctly parse this input string using your given Schema.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The ConvertJsonToAvro-processor adds an attribute named "error" with the value Cannot convert field MAC: Cannot convert to fixed: "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005" to the error output stream

Comment: I tested using the Avro `JSONDecoder`, so there might be some subtle difference difference when using NiFi... is your MAC field nullable or in a union by any chance?

Comment: The schema I'm using in the ConvertJsonToAvro-processor is identical to the one stated in my question above.

Comment: I've also tried your alternative, but this gives the following error: "Cannot convert field MAC: Cannot convert to fixed: {"MY_FIXED_TYPE":"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005"}"

Comment: You may be better off using ConvertRecord with a JsonTreeReader and AvroRecordSetWriter, the record-based processors are usually better at conversions than ConvertJsonToAvro

Comment: @mattyb unfortunately not a solution. Tested with both JSON-input alternatives in your post, but got error "java.lang.ClassCastException; java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericFixed" for the first JSON-form and 
"Cannot convert value MapRecord[{MY_FIXED_TYPE=}] of type class org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.MapRecord to a ByteBuffer." for the 2nd JSON-form

Comment: The above answer is not correct for NiFi, which does NOT use Avro JSON decoding as defined in the Avro spec!  My apologies for this mistaken assumption.

Comment: @fstuijt What version of NiFi are you using? Sounds like you're running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5662